# How can I use sql data in header link?

Tags: sql, post, get, header

I need to use a variable from SQL. I can print which I wrote the variable. But I can't use 
it when it out of while query.

Here is the SQL:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM organize WHERE organize.nid=$nid"))
{
    // display records if there are records to display
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            echo $row->nid;
            echo $row->omid;

            $id=$row->omid;
        }
    }
    // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
    else
    {
        echo "No results to display!";
    }
}
// show an error if there is an issue with the database query
else
{
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

And the header under this scripts.

```
header("Refresh: 10;http://localhost/records.php?mid= $id ");
```

I know this is not right way. But I show you what I want. Need to use that 'omid' in header inseat of '$id'.

Comment: It's a **variable** (not a *veriable*)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved it. This scripts like the above codes. I didn't understand why It didn't work. Maybe because I should not use

```
echo $row->nid;

echo $row->omid;
```

or

```
 $id=$row->omid;
```

The right usage is as follows:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
                                    {


                         $dd=$row->omid;

                                   }

header("Refresh: 2;http://localhost/records.php?mid= $dd");
```